# how to further encapsulate one form field component?

Tags: angular

right now I use ngx-daterangepicker-material in many places with the below duplicate code, I want to encapsulate as independent component for reuse.

```
<div class="fx-date-range-container">
  <span class="summary">Summary</span>
  <input class="fx-date-range" type="text" matInput
         ngxDaterangepickerMd
         [locale]="{applyLabel: 'ok', format: 'MM-DD-YYYY'}"
         [drops]="'down'"
         [opens]="'right'"
         [ranges]="ranges"
         [showCustomRangeLabel]="false"
         [alwaysShowCalendars]="true"
         [keepCalendarOpeningWithRange]="true"
         [showCancel]="true"
         autocomplete="off"
         [(ngModel)]="selectedDateRange"
         (change)="getCampaignFXASummary()"
         name="daterange"/>
  <mat-icon class="icon-date-range" matSuffix>keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
</div>
```

the component name is fx-date-range-picker.
here is demo, my question is how to set ngModel and pass the value into fx-date-range-picker component.

maybe I should implement writeValue function, but not sure how to write.

https://ngx-daterangepicker-material-demo.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement ControlValueAccessor

see `angular.io` documantation about it
[ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor)

The functions to implement should look like:

```
  export class [yourClass] implements ControlValueAccessor {      
  protected onChange: (value: any) => void = NOOP;
  protected internalValue: number;

  get value(): number {
    return this.internalValue;
  }

  set value(value: number) {
    if (value !== this.internalValue) {
      this.internalValue = value;
      this.onChange(value);
    }
  }

  writeValue(value) {
    this.value = value;
}
registerOnChange(fn) { this.onChange = fn;  }
registerOnTouched(fn) {  }
```

see below post that explain it:
https://blog.angularindepth.com/never-again-be-confused-when-implementing-controlvalueaccessor-in-angular-forms-93b9eee9ee83

Good luck!